# UIView setFrame custom implementation

Tags: objective-c, uiview, overriding, subclass

I have a subclass of `UIView` which I'll refer to as `MyView`. Can anyone identify any possible undesirable side effects of overriding `setFrame` in the following way:

```
- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)newFrame {

    CGPoint newCentre;

    newCentre.x = newFrame.origin.x + newFrame.size.width / 2.f;
    newCentre.y = newFrame.origin.y + newFrame.size.height/ 2.f;

    [super setCenter:newCentre];

    newFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(newFrame.size, self.bounds.size) == NO) {
        [super setBounds:newFrame];
    }    
}
```

I know the above is a very strange implementation and do not wish to get into a discussion about *why* I am not using `[super setFrame]` - but I am interested to know are there any ramifications from not using the super implementation?

Comment: afaik `setCenter:` modifies the frame (implying that it calls `setFrame:` internally), so your implementation does use `[super setFrame:]` except through setting the center of the view. Other than that - I cannot see any "ramifications" per se. I would, however, use `CGRectGet*` methods. IMHO It makes code more readable.

Comment: I'm not convinced that `[super setCenter:]` does call `[super setFrame:]` implicitly. The [docs](http://bit.ly/Na5QJ2) for `center` state "Setting this property **changes the values** of the frame properties accordingly." Whereas the `frame` docs state "Setting this property **changes the point specified by the center property and the size in the bounds rectangle accordingly**". These descriptions mean that we would get infinite recursion if what you say is true. Seems more likely that changing one changes the **values** of the other, but not through a call to the setter methods in question.

Comment: To check this I setup a small project (on GitHub at git://github.com/ryanggrey/UIViewSetFrameSetCenterTest.git) that calls my above implementation of `setFrame` and then the super implementation of `setFrame` a few million times each. I deliberately change the `origin` of the frame but not the `size` every iteration so that my above implementation might benefit from the `if` statement in order to show the difference. If you CPU profile this, the above implementation is a fair bit faster. If `setCenter` did call `setFrame` then wouldn't both implementations take roughly the same amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not take into account **`transform`**. Setting bounds size to frame size applies only when the transform is “identity” (`CGAffineTransformIdentity`).

Also I would check how observing methods ([KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)) are called. You are changing `center` and `bounds` by an observable setter.